# Configure a js library to tell webpack to use the ES6 module dist file

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, import, module

I maintain a library that has has a **/dist** folder with versions for CommonJS, ES6 modules, and direct `<script>` loading.

The **package.json** file is configured to identify each version:

```json
   "type": "module",
   "main": "dist/pretty-print-json.umd.cjs",
   "module": "dist/pretty-print-json.esm.js",
   "browser": "dist/pretty-print-json.min.js",
```

When the library is installed:

```
$ npm install pretty-print-json
```

and imported:

```
import { prettyPrintJson } from 'pretty-print-json';
```

into a project with **webpack**, IDEs correctly interpret the ES6 module version plus the TypeScript declaration file (**dist/pretty-print-json.d.ts**).

However, the build process fails:

```
./src/app/app.component.ts:74:13-35 - Error: export 'prettyPrintJson' (imported
as 'prettyPrintJson') was not found in 'pretty-print-json' (module has no
exports)
```

The ES6 module version has an `export` statement:

```js
export { prettyPrintJson };
```

After a bunch of experiments with a simple Angular project, I figured out that **webpack** is using the `"browser"` version instead of the `"module"` version.

How do you configure a library so that **webpack** correctly picks up the `"module"` version without breaking support for the other versions?

Answer (score 1):

The `browser` field takes priority over `module` and `main` if your target is the browser.

I found this solution for your problem:

```
{
    "name": "main-module-browser",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "module": "dist/index.esm.js",
    "browser": {
            "./dist/index.js": "./dist/index.browser.js",
            "./dist/index.esm.js": "./dist/index.browser.esm.js"
    }
}
```